# How to use the (short) git commit hash to tag image versions in Docker Compose file

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

From the [official Docker Compose build doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build):

> If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image:

Example:

```
build: 
   ...
image: myapp:tag
```

but I would like to replace `tag` with the output of `git rev-parse --short HEAD`.

Ideally I need something like:

```
image: myapp:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```

Comment: I don't think the compose file can do anything more complex than interpolating environment variables, so you could do `COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) docker-compose ...` then use `image: myapp:${COMMIT}`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This looks useful for my situation too. I put this in my .env but it outputs "$(git rev-parse...." as a string and doesn't execute.
SHORT_SHA = $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)

Comment: @JeremySchultz I mean _on the command line_, where that actually gets evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

The [build `ARGS`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) section illustrates [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182601/how-to-use-the-short-git-commit-hash-to-tag-image-versions-in-docker-compose-f#comment95194117_54182601)

You need to set an environment variable first, and declare the ARGS in your `docker-compose.yml`

```
ARG commit
...
image: "myapp:${commit}"
```

See "[variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution)" and also [The “`env_file`” configuration option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

> Your configuration options can contain environment variables.
> Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which `docker-compose` is run.

Any hope of running a command directly in the `docker-compose.yml` file was ruled out with [`docker/compose` issue 4081](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4081).